# Laravel : How to get the first record of each collections in a 'with' function query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get a collection of all artists with their latest image only.

The following code returns a collection of all artists but with only one image associated with the first artist.

```
$data = Artist::with(['images' => function($q){
            $q->first();
        }])
        ->get();

return $data;
```

My models:

```
class Artist extends Model {  
   public function images() 
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image');
   }
}

class Image extends Model {  
    public function artists() 
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set in you modal:

```
public function FirstImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('image');
}
```

then:

```
$data = Artist::with('FirstImage')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I may miss something here but it looks like this will return the first artist. I want all artists with their first image...

Comment: i changed the answer. now you will get all items with first image